# cufon LTR to RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, right-to-left, cufon

I got this [site](http://www.fresh-air.co.il/)

I'm using cufon to convert text to my own font.

The problem is that the text is shown in reverse.

I'm using JavaScript file called `cunfonRTL.js`, the content is:

```
var CufonRTLClass=(function(){
        this.RTL = RTL;

   function RTL(tagName) {
        $(tagName)/*.css('font-size', '19px')*/.wrapInner('<bdo class="cufon" dir=ltr></bdo>');

        $('bdo.cufon').each(function()    {
        var word = $(this).text();
        var splittext = word.split("");
        var reversedtext = splittext.reverse();
        var newtext = reversedtext.join("");
        $(this).text(newtext);
        });

    }
});

CufonRTL = new CufonRTLClass;
```

The rendered text look like this:

```
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="כותרת " style="width: 80px; height: 28px; "><canvas width="110" height="28" style="width: 110px; height: 28px; top: 4px; left: -8px; "></canvas><cufontext>כותרת </cufontext></cufon>
```

Its 'cufon' alright but its not RTL.. its LTR..
I'm having syntax problem?

Help will be very appreciated.

UPDATE:
In chrome's console I found this:
[image]

this is how I call the functions:

```
 Cufon.replace('H1');
CufonRTL.RTL('H1');
```

UPDATE:
As far as I know there is a jQuery conflict with the $ selectors.
I converted all my $ sings with `jQuery`
There is no exception now, its just dont run.

I did some debugging and discovered he is not getting inside this loop:
`jQuery('bdo.cufon').each(function()`

```
var CufonRTLClass=(function(){
        this.RTL = RTL;

   function RTL(tagName) {
        jQuery(tagName)/*.css('font-size', '19px')*/.wrapInner('<bdo class="cufon" dir=ltr></bdo>');

        jQuery('bdo.cufon').each(function()    {
        var word = jQuery(this).text();
        var splittext = word.split("");
        var reversedtext = splittext.reverse();
        var newtext = reversedtext.join("");
        jQuery(this).text(newtext);
        });

    }
});

CufonRTL = new CufonRTLClass;
```

help?

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
$(tagName)/*.css('font-size', '19px')*/.wrapInner('<bdo class="cufon" dir=ltr></bdo>');
```

To this

```
$(tagName)/*.css('font-size', '19px')*/.wrapInner('<bdo class="cufon" dir=rtl></bdo>');
```

Comment: Did you use `jQuery.noConflict();` before changing all the `$` with `jQuery`?

Comment: put it here `jQuery.noConflict()
   function RTL(tagName) {`. I think that there is a conflict and it wont run because of that

Comment: I created new namespace `J` and changed all the jQuery to J, to avoid conflict, but there is still a problem.. I've wrote 2 alerts, one out side a function and one inside. function:`jQuery('bdo.cufon').each(function()`. The alert that inside the function is not runnning

Comment: Since you changed them to `J`, you should be using `J('bdo.cufon').each(function()`.

Comment: Well, my friend, I can't seem to know what your problem is... are you sure you changed the line to this `$(tagName)/*.css('font-size', '19px')*/.wrapInner('<bdo class="cufon" dir=rtl></bdo>');` after using `jQuery.noConflict();`?

Comment: yes, but the problem is that the jquery is not working.. thanks for help tho